# Proxmox networking configuration

Tags: networking, proxmox

I have recently bought a test dedicated server to test proxmox. The installation went smoothly, but i get stuck in the network configuration

I'm given the IP: 192.151.154.146/29

After proxmox installation, the `interfaces` was

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.151.154.146
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 192.151.154.144
        broadcast 192.151.154.151
        gateway 192.151.154.145
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
        dns-search nocix.net
```

I followed proxmox tutorial and change the content of the `/etc/network/interfaces` to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address  192.151.154.146
        netmask  255.255.255.248
        gateway  192.151.154.145
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.151.154.147
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

My objective is to create a LXC that has address `192.151.154.148`. This is the configuration:

[LXC creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glusw.png)

This is the `interfaces` of the created LXC container:

[LXC interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKzeO.png)

Unfortunately the created LXC container cannot connect to internet.

Could any one tell me what i am doing wrongly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bridge_ports none
```

You should have an interface declared in vmbr0 for yours LXC :
replace by :

```
bridge_ports eth0
```

More precisely,
In your proxmox server configuration, you should have :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.151.154.146
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

and in your LXC :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address  192.151.154.148
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create your LXC Container with your CIDR equal to 32:

192.151.154.148/32 instead of 192.151.154.148/29.

If it don't works, if you are using IP Fail Over, your server provider will give you a mac adress to set on your container to use with this IP.

Your mac adress set is the provider's one ?

Comment: Thank you, i used 192.151.154.148/29 during LXC container. Now it works following Sorcha answer